# IntelliJ can't resolve com.amazonaws symbols

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, gradle, amazon-s3

this may be a very simple question, but I've been stuck on it for hours...

I'm trying to add amazon cloud integrations into my project, and I can't seem to get the project to recognize the jar files.  I'm currently simply trying to instantiate an AmazonS3 client:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
```

I've added this to my build.gradle under dependencies{ }:

```
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.6')
```

When I run gradle build, it looks like it is downloading a bunch of jar files from maven, but when I go to compile my project, I get "symbol not found" errors.

```
error: cannot find symbol
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
        ^
```

It seems like gradle isn't adding the classes to my classpath or something.  Is there some plugin I need?  Do I need to add the jars manually to my project?

Thanks

Edit: I'm using IntelliJ Idea to manage the project.

Comment: Can Gradle compile the project? If so, Intellij needs to update the project files. This may be of help: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html

Comment: Gradle cannot compile either.  I suppose this means the problem lies in my project setup, as opposed to intellij

Comment: Have you allowed your Gradle to download dependencies?

Comment: I believe so.  When adding a -i flag to gradle, the log describes downloading pom and jar files that match the aws services I would expect it to download.  How do I know if it is downloaded?

Comment: Yup. The `-i` already tell you that Gradle is downloading your dependencies. Could you check the Gradle download all transitive dependencies? In this case, download `aws-java-sdk-s3`,  `aws-java-sdk-core`, etc.

Comment: I checked the Gradle Cache, and the jar files are all there as far as I can see.  (~/Users/Brian/.gradle/....)   However they don't seem to be added to my classpath.  Many other libraries are added from the cache, but not these.  Not sure why.

Comment: After a 'gradle clean', 'gradle cleanIdea', then 'gradle idea', and 'gradle build', I see "ideaModule
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.10.6/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6-sources.jar"

After this, I can import the Amazon classes.  I'm not sure why it couldn't find it before...

Comment: sometime Invalidating Caches and restarting intelliJ can also resolve this issue - File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... (on Mac) and IntelliJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the problem was before, but I was able to resolve it by:

```
gradle clean
gradle cleanIdea
gradle idea
...
<import required classes>
...
gradle build
```

Seems like this resolved it.  Something was wrong with the project setup.