# Android Studio Gradle: Cannot resolve symbol 'amazonaws'

Tags: android, gradle, amazon-s3

I'm having an issue with importing amazonaws in my gradle and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Problem:**

I'm attempting to import 'com.amazonaws.auth.*' into my build.gradle, however a red line appears under the statement stating "Cannot resolve symbol 'amazonaws'".

**What I've attempted:**

- Sync Gradle and rebuild
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Attempted to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637680/intellij-cant-resolve-com-amazonaws-symbols) to no avail

**build.gradle code:**

```
buildscript {
    ...

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.5'
    }
}

import com.amazonaws.auth.*

def getAwsReadOnlyCredentials = {
    ...
    return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()
}

AWSCredentials libraryCredentials = getAwsReadOnlyCredentials()

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            ...
        }
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Could you resolve the problem??

Answer (score 1):

you need to import the [artifacts](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws) from repository `mavenCentral()` - 
and don't add dependencies into the `buildscript` `classpath`, but a module's `dependencies`. it seems to me, as if you were mixing up Java with Gradle syntax, while depending on the wrong one library. this `import` statement and the `AWSCredentials` (with a high probability) belong into a `.java` file and not a `.gradle` file.

for example: this one looks promising:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.31"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just Invalidating the caches and restarting the android studio solved the problem. In order to do that you need to go to the `Files -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart`.

We do not need the `mavenCentral()` repository to be exact to download the aws dependencies. Only `jcenter()` should suffice.

And also consider adding `apply plugin 'java'` in your `build.gradle`.